# Highcharts - Can't run example

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, callback

I'm a beginner with HIGHCHARTS.

I want to start from this example :
http://people.canonical.com/~bradf/media/highstock/examples/basic-line/index.htm

I downloaded the corresponding JSON file :

http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json

And I want to run it locally (and after test it with my own JSON files).
But it doesn't works!

I use the source code of the example, I've just modified the getJSON line.

I have this :

```
$.getJSON('./data/json/'+ name+'-c.json&callback=?', function(data) { ... }
```

I think that the issue comes from the callback.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the example working on your local you will have to follow the below steps:

1. I assume that the json source code you have downloaded from the url http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json is stored in a file `data.json`
2. Now as you would have noticed, the json source in the file `data.json` would be like as below:

   ```
   ?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */
   [

   /* May 2006 */
   [1147651200000,67.79],
   [1147737600000,64.98],
   [1147824000000,65.26],
   [1147910400000,63.18],
   .......
   ....
   ```

**So now as you would have noticed there are code lines `?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */`  and `/* May 2006 */` in the json source which are causing the things to go wrong by generating a parse error because the data source with such code lines is not a valid json string.**

**So you will have to remove each and every such invalid code line from the whole json file to make the things working correctly.**

After removing all the invalid line of code your json file should look like:

```
[
[1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
....
...
]
```

3. Now till this step you are ready with a valid json data source for the Highstock chart, so finally to display the chart you will have to use the code like:

```
$(function() {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

 });
```

**The whole page source code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

     });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&callback=?` is normally appended for [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which is a technique used for cross domain calls (to other websites for example.)

From what I can see you should try removing it from the call.
In your case:

`$.getJSON('./data/json/'+ name+'-c.json,  function(data) { ... }`